# Using exception in g++

Tags: c++, exception

Getting compiler error in the below code which is throwing `std::exception`  in g++ 4.8.2 on linux.
Any suggestion why this error is coming will be very helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void function()
{
     std::exception e((char*)"mmmm");
     throw e;
}


int main(int argc, const char* arg[]) {

    try {
        function();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**error:**

```
$ g++ t.cpp
t.cpp: In function ‘void function()’:
t.cpp:6:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::exception::exception(char*)’
   std::exception e((char*)"mmmm");
                                 ^
t.cpp:6:33: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from t.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception:63:5: note: std::exception::exception()
     exception() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception:63:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception:60:9: note: std::exception::exception(const std::exception&)
   class exception
         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception:60:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char*’ to ‘const std::exception&’
```

**EDIT 1**

But code is compiling and working well in Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

```
_EXCEPTION_INLINE __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL exception::exception()
    : _Mywhat(NULL), _Mydofree(false) { }

_EXCEPTION_INLINE __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL exception::exception(const char * const & _What)
    : _Mywhat(NULL), _Mydofree(false)
    {
    _Copy_str(_What);
    }

_EXCEPTION_INLINE __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL exception::exception(const char * const & _What, int)
    : _Mywhat(_What), _Mydofree(false) { }

_EXCEPTION_INLINE __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL exception::exception(const exception& _That)
    : _Mywhat(NULL), _Mydofree(false)
```

What the C++ standard says about this?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial on concurrency https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0pCft99K74 and at 13:40 there is the line of code throw(std::exception("E")); and I get  no matching function for call to ‘std::exception::exception(const char [2]). He's using VS, so maybe it does have something to do with g++?

Answer (score 12):

[`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) does not have a constructor that takes a std::string or a char*. Maybe you'd like to use [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)?

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out in other answers, the constructor for `std::exception` takes no arguments.
Your code compiles in MSVC because

```
exception(const char* const &message)
exception(const char* const &message, int)
```

are Microsoft extension to the C++ Standard Library
(see Remarks here [exception Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/exception-class?view=msvc-160))

Answer (score 1):

`no matching function for call to ...` means that you are trying to call a function that doesn't exist. `std::exception` has no constructor that takes a `char*`, or anything that can be converted from a `char*`. It only has a default constructor, and a copy constructor.

Comment: How can it be if my code runs in MSVC? trying to compile with g++ getting errors no such constructor indeed. but why in visual studio it works it baffles me.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue and trying to learn why as well.

Comment: "The Microsoft implementation includes non-standard constructors taking strings thus allowing instances to be thrown directly with a meaningful error message." https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception